# Time Series forecasting with an additional data point in the future

Tags: regression, time-series

I have 3 year's worth of revenue build-up data (52 weeks, weekly) from 2015 - 2018. So, it is a revenue build-up curve on a yearly basis.

Something like this, with different colors describing different years. 
[image]

Hypothetically, if I have one single data point in the future, say 4 weeks into 2019, can I do time series taking this extra data point that I have into account? Can I "join"/predict the beginning week of 2019 to the 4th week of 2019 (data pt that I have) somehow? (short of drawing a straight line to the future data pt)

Is there something like this? I'm exploring rnn, arima, prophet but none of them seems to be able to cater for this.

The only method I can think of is to use regression, but this didn't give me satisfactory results, it's under-predicting by a lot.

Looking for some ideas on how to model this.

Answer (score 1):

You may ultimately want to predict the cumulative , but  you will be better served to model the actual weekly (observed) data and predict that and then impute the annual cumulative. If you post your 4*52=208 actual values I night be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks, It is cumulative revenue build-up currently. I can't really post the actual values as this is company data.

Comment: Then scale the data by subtracting a constant and then divide by another constant or simply create a similar time series to yours.